# How to force GTM to add tag in the <head>?

Tags: javascript, html, google-tag-manager, adsense

I've followed the below steps for adding AdSense script inside of my website:

1. Now that you have the code head over to GTM.
2. Create a new tag.
3. Provide a name.
4. Select custom HTML as the tag template.
5. Copy and paste the code into the text field.
6. Set the trigger to fire on All pages or the pages you want to serve ads on.
7. Click Save and Submit to push the code live.

I did it and all fine. Here is my full code: (define as a tag in google tag manager)

```
<script async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<script>
  (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({
    google_ad_client: "ca-pub-<token>",
    enable_page_level_ads: true
  });
</script>
```

### The problem is:

Script above will be added to the dom separately. I mean, this part:

```
<script async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
```

appends to the `<head>` section, and this part:

```
<script>
  (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({
    google_ad_client: "ca-pub-<token>",
    enable_page_level_ads: true
  });
</script>
```

appends to the `<body>` section. So Google AdSense says:

> The code is missing or incomplete

Any idea how can I make GTM force to add both scripts right after each other inside `<head>` section?

Comment: You can create a script element and append it to the head. However since this will only happen after GTM has loaded this is in all probability pointless.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$('head').append('<script>
  (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({
    google_ad_client: "ca-pub-<token>",
    enable_page_level_ads: true
  });
</script>');
<script>
```