# Uncaught TypeError: firebase.messaging is not a function

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Here is my code:

```
    <script>

        // Your web app's Firebase configuration
        var firebaseConfig = {
            apiKey: "<from firebase>",
            authDomain: "<from firebase>",
            databaseURL: "<from firebase>",
            projectId: "<from firebase>",
            storageBucket: "",
            messagingSenderId: "<from firebase>",
            appId: "<from firebase>"
        };
        // Initialize Firebase
        firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);


        // [START get_messaging_object]
        // Retrieve Firebase Messaging object.
        const messaging = firebase.messaging();

    </script>
```

This line `firebase.messaging();` throws:

> Uncaught TypeError: firebase.messaging is not a function at

Noted that the result of `console.log(firebase)` is:

[image]

Any idea what's the problem?

Comment: Can you edit your question to show how you include the Firebase SDK(s)?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen The problem was, lack of adding `<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.3.1/firebase-messaging.js"></script>` in the top of the page. Now I've faced with a new issue .. it's SSL certificate on localhost .. I use xampp and on localhost firebase doesn't work apparently (because when I upload my code on the server, it worked well)

Comment: Yeah, that's sort of what I expected, which is why I asked to see the includes. :)
Good to hear that you got it fixed. Feel free to either self-answer, or close as a temporary issue/typo level problem.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Sure I will add a self-answer .. just since you have lots of reputation on google tools (specially firebase), can you please take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57134297/6381081) and let me know if you have any comment? I really stuck on it.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you didn't follow the basic integration steps from the documentation. There is an include for messaging:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.7.0/firebase-messaging.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

You must included import '@firebase/messaging' for it to work. So it's supposed to look like this:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import '@firebase/messaging';
```

Original answerd:
[TypeError: firebase.messaging is not a function in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44308901/typeerror-firebase-messaging-is-not-a-function-in-node-js/44309060)

Comment: OP is directly including the SDK's in HTML. There are not using NodeJs.